# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>' to 'int'

Tags: c#, sql-server

My code :

```
int key = 0;
            //get primary key of inserted row
            key = db.Query("SELECT max(event_id) FROM event where title=" + cevent.title +  "AND description=" + cevent.description + "AND event_start=" + cevent.start  + "AND event_end=" + cevent.end);
```

Error message :

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'int'

I am using C#, WebMatrix and SQL Server. WebMatrix. If I try and run ExecuteScalar instead of Query, I get

> 'WebMatrix.Data.Database' does not contain a definition for
>   'ExecuteScalar'

Does anyone know what I can do to fix my code?

Comment: maybe `db.Query` returns an IEnumerable instead of int?? the error message is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`Database.QueryValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.queryvalue%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) instead.

```
// No need to declare it beforehand...
int key = (int) db.QueryValue(...);
```

And as in your previous question, you should absolutely *not* be embedding the query parameter values within the SQL.

`Database.QueryValue` is documented as:

> Executes a SQL query that returns a single scalar value as the result.

... which sounds exactly right to me. It would be worth browsing through the docs - they're not very detailed, but it would at least show you what's available.

Comment: Don't worry, this will be fixed after I get it working! Many thanks for the response :

Answer (score 0):

Your `key` is integer you can not cast an integer `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`, as message claimes.

If you are *sure* that there is only one result, write something like this:

```
 key = (int)db.Query("SELECT max(event_id) FROM event where title=" + 
                           cevent.title +  "AND description=" + 
                           cevent.description + "AND event_start=" + 
                           cevent.start  + "AND event_end=" + cevent.end).
                           FirstOrDefault();
```

*Should* be enough to you.

Comment: If you're sure there is only one result, then `SingleOrDefault()` would be more appropriate than `FirstOrDefault()`.